# Hibernate append table alias in query.

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have this in my user.java:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name="users")

 public class Users_Model implements Serializable{

 @Id @GeneratedValue
 private Long id;   
 @ColumnTransformer(
        read="AES_DECRYPT(userName, 'Hf7p4u6e')",
        write="AES_ENCRYPT(?, 'Hf7p4u6e')")
 }
```

I used aes_decrypt to retrieve the values in my database which is encrypted. My problem is it's only decrypt the english characters but not the japanese or chinese characters. The output I get is :`Hello ����������` it should be: `Hello 한국어/조선말`.

I tried to display the query and this is what I got:

```
select message_mo0_.id as id0_, CONVERT(AES_DECRYPT(message_mo0_.createdBy, 'Hf7p4u6e') message_mo0_.USING message_mo0_.utf8) as userName_, from users message_mo0_
```

As you can see it appends the table alias in my query in `using utf8` so everytime I get `error sql  syntax correct`. My question is there a way to tell the hibernate not to append table alias. I would like to generate a query which looks like this to where the `using utf8` is no appended table alias:

```
select message_mo0_.id as id0_, CONVERT(AES_DECRYPT(message_mo0_.createdBy, 'Hf7p4u6e') USING utf8) as userName_, from users message_mo0_
```

I've been stuck here for almost 4 days. Please help. Thank you in advance

Comment: How/when is the query generated by Hibernate? I mean, what are you using for generating the query? hql, Criteria?

Comment: No I didn't use criteria